# How to make groups of test scripts

Tags: squish

Lets say I have several test suites:

---

suite_first

- tst_first_1
- tst_first_2
- tst_first_3

---

suite_second

- tst_second_1

---

suite_third

- tst_third_1
- tst_third_2

---

I can execute each suite from Squish GUI by single run.

But what if I want to run collection of test scripts from different suites... For example, I need to execute `tst_first_2`, `tst_second_1`, `tst_third_1` just like separate suite

Is there any possibility to create groups of specific scripts from different suites to be able to execute them via single run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not possible yet.

You can hack around this by creating a "dummy" test suite on the fly into which you "link" the desired test cases, for example via symbolic file system links.

If the test suites have separate Global Script configurations or separate object maps it will probably be difficult or even impossible to use this approach.

Please file a feature request with the vendor.

Comment: Based on your answer I've filtered all required test-scripts by keyword (applied decorator) and created symbolic links for each of them: `ln -s -f test_script_name /path/to/dummy_suite/test_script_name`. And now I'm able to run them as separate suite

Answer (score 1):

Squish IDE currently supports only one suite at a time, by default. But, you can easily achieve this using a batch file, passing the required test cases of each suites to the squish runner. [Playback option --testcase](https://doc.froglogic.com/squish/latest/rg-cmdline.html#rg-squishrunner-cli-playback--testcase).

This Type of test case selection is also possible via Squish plugins for other build automation tools like Jenkins.

You might be able to call test cases from different suites by creating a dummy suite but I wouldn't recommend that because consistency concerns.

Comment: Your link is for the older Squish 6.1 version. Please use this link to refer to the current version: https://doc.froglogic.com/squish/latest/rg-cmdline.html#rg-squishrunner-cli--testsuite